# Error: El fragment queda visible cuando me devuelvo al fragment anterior

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo 3 fragmentos
1 fragmentListarArticulos.....
 en este fragmento obtengo datos desde un webservice y lleno un Recycler View..
al clicar un item me lleva al segundo fragment fragmentDinamicoCompra en este confirmo un pedido y lleno un tableLayout en un tercer frgment fregmentListaCarrito......
hasta ahi todo correcto pero cuando me devuelvo del fragmentListaCarrito al fragment fragmentListarArticulos con los articulos listado el tercer fragment se ve por encima del primero...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

fragmentListarArticulos
 @Override

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflar el diseño de este fragmento
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmento_listar_articulos, container, false);

    lstRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstRecycler);
    contruirRecycler(view);

    return view;
}
```

public void contruirRecycler(View view){

```
    Utilidades.OP="lista";
    lstRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstRecycler);

    if(Utilidades.visualizacion==Utilidades.LIST){
        lstRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
    }
    else{
        lstRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(),2));
        lstRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    obtenerArticulos();
}
```

/*OnClick del recycler*/

```
   ArticulosImagenUrlAdapter adapter = new ArticulosImagenUrlAdapter(lstArticulos,getContext());
        adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
           /*String codigo=lstArticulos.get(lstRecycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getCodigo();
             String articulo=lstArticulos.get(lstRecycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getArticulo();
             String precio=lstArticulos.get(lstRecycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getPrecioV();*/

             Utilidades.articulo = lstArticulos.get(lstRecycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getArticulo();
             Utilidades.codigo = lstArticulos.get(lstRecycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getCodigo();
             Utilidades.precio =  Integer.parseInt(lstArticulos.get(lstRecycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getPrecioV());
             Utilidades.imagen = lstArticulos.get(lstRecycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getRuta_imagen();

             Fragment fragment = new FragmentoDinamicoCompra();
             FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment);
             transaction.addToBackStack(null);
             transaction.commit();
           //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Selección: "+ lstArticulos.get(lstRecycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getRuta_imagen(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

/*al clicar el producto me abre el siguiente fragmento*/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al precionar el boton agregar al carrito se llena un tableLayout en el tercer fragmento que se ve a continuacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando me devuelvo de este fragmento a la lista.. la lista queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es bueno que agregues el código con el que llamas cada fragmento para saber cual es el origen del error.

Comment: No estoy utilizando código para el regreso....
Solo presionando el botón "atrás" que traen todo los android.
En los fragmentos me muevo con el siguiente código
/******************/
  Fragment fragment = new FragmentoDinamicoCompra();
                 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment);
                 transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                 transaction.commit();
/************************/
La cosa es que para volver "atrás" solo estoy utilizando el botón del celular

Comment: Puedes agregar el **xml** del activity.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código del xml en ella y elimina la respuesta que has agregado. Por casualidad tendrías el proyecto en GitHub para echarle un vistazo.